# getting the facebook photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I have a problem with getting photos using facebook graph API. I'm getting the empty result.

Permissions that i gave:

```
$par['req_perms'] = "publish_stream,
                 offline_access,
                 user_status, user_photos or friend_photos, 
                 user_videos or friend_videos, read_stream,
                 user_likes or friend_likes, 
                 user_events or friend_events,
                 email, user_groups";
```

Comment: You need to post example code. Without it, this is a very vague question.

Comment: i used normal github example by editting

http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Comment: these are the permissions i gave

  $par['req_perms'] = "publish_stream,
                    offline_access,
                    user_status,
                    user_photos or friend_photos,
                    user_videos or friend_videos,
                    read_stream,
                    user_likes or friend_likes,
                    user_events or friend_events,
                    email,
                    user_groups";

Comment: it is work for this

$feeds = $facebook->api('/'."userid".'/feed?limit=25');


not for this

  $albums = $facebook->api('/'."userid".'/photos);

Answer (score 1):

You need to comma separate each permission. You can't say "...user_photos or friend_photos...", you need to say "...user_photos,friend_photos..."

Comment: Yes, I have. You need to make sure you visit a page with the req_perms code on it so the user you're looking up has granted the corrected permissions.

Comment: this is the output i am getting after decoding 

array(1) { ["data"]=>  array(0) { } } 

an empty array

Comment: I meant, after you changed the code to have the permissions declared the way I mentioned, you need to visit a page on your app as the user you're trying to get pictures from. That way, it will ask for the correct permissions, and then you can perform the lookup you need.

Comment: yes now it asks me for permissions but return empty array.

even though i ask user informations it doesn't give me "user like pages" list

Comment: i get the like pages adding "/likes" at the end of the requesting url

Comment: @Mike Sherov  i need help for getting photos